# unexpected behaviour with SwiftUI .constant(nil) binding in SheetView

Tags: swiftui

I came across some issues with my SwiftUI code.

I made a simple example.

Just a Button that opens a Sheet.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showSheet.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView(show: $showSheet, selectedDate: .constant(nil))
        }
    }
}
```

The Sheet has an optional Binding.

You can close it via the mark button.

However, as soon as I use an @Environment wrapper, the xmark stops working.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @Binding var selectedDate: Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, \(selectedDate?.description ?? "Welt")!")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            self.show = false
                            
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                .renderingMode(.original)
                                .accessibilityLabel(Text("Save"))
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

(This seems to be due to the view constantly refreshing itself?)

In addition: This only happens on my iPhone 12 Pro Max.
In the simulator or an iPhone 11 Pro Max it is working fine.
(Don't have any other devices to test on.)

If I don't use .constant(nil) but give it a $Date, it works just fine.
If I remove the @Environment, it also works.

Am I doing something wrong here?
What is my mistake?

Comment: Which iOS version is on iPhone 12 Pro Max?

Comment: @Asperi My iOS version is 14.4 on both phones.